# What is the use of pattern object?

Tags: dart

What is the use of pattern object if we can directly implement second option?

```
Pattern pattern = r'^[0-9]*$';
RegExp regex = RegExp(pattern);
```

vs

```
RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^[0-9]*$');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pattern` is an abstract base class for `RegExp` and `String`.  As with any other base class, you'd use it in places where you want to accept any derived implementations and to take advantage of polymorphism.  For example, [`String.indexOf`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/indexOf.html) and [`String.contains`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/contains.html) take `Pattern` arguments.